# how change title after click checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

this is my snippet:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-captcha',
  templateUrl: './captcha.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./captcha.component.css']
})
export class CaptchaComponent implements OnInit {


  captcha="click case for change title";

  peut:boolean=true;
  oui:boolean=true;
  nom:boolean=true;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    cocher(){
      console.log(this.peut,"**");
      if(this.peut === false){ this.captcha == "title is changed!"};
    }
}
```

```html
<h2 [(ngModel)]="captcha">{{captcha}}</h2>
<div>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="peut" (change)="cocher()" >peut-être ?</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="oui"  (change)="cocher()" >oui ?</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="non"  (change)="cocher()">non ?</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

How I must do for load title correctly.
I have à erreur with firebug:
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

thank's for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code of this fucntion  like this

```
cocher(){
      console.log(this.peut,"**");
      if(!this.peut){
         this.captcha ="title is changed!";
      }
    }
```

Comment: tank's four reply, my problème when we load first time , the title is not here .

Comment: i found 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.captcha ="click case for change title";
  }

  cocher(){
    console.log(this.peut,"**");
    this.peut? this.captcha ="title is changed!": this.captcha ="click case for change title";
    
  }, but we must wait 2 secondes.